не получается сделать валидацию в rails
У меня rails 7.1 и ruby 3.2.0.
Я хочу сделать выделение цветом поля формы при ошибке заполнения. У меня работает сама валидация, но нету класса .field_with_errors. Тогда я попробовал использовать конструкцию if. Но она тоже не работает. Код формы:
<%= form_with model: @question do |f| %>
  <div class="mb-3 row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
      <% if !@question.errors[:title] %>
        <div class = "error">
          <%= f.label :title%>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <%= f.label :title %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <% if !@question.errors[:title] %>
        <div class = "error">
          <%= f.text_field :title, require: true, placeholder: 'Title', class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, require: true, placeholder: 'Title', class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3 row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
      <%= f.label :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: 'Body', class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit question!", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>```

